# Having trouble displaying bluetooth devices in textView

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like the device names to show up in the textView of my app when they are found during scanning but nothing shows up.

I see the bluetooth is successfully enabled and my other device is visible but nothing ever shows up.

```
bluetoothAdapter = (BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());
    bluetoothAdapter.enable();
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            //Finding devices
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                textView.append(device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

I know the above code was kinda intended for use in a listView but would it not still work in textView?

Comment: If just above the line `textView.append(device.getAddress());` you put a Toast e.g. `Toast.makeText(getContext(),device.getAddress(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and tell us what if the Toast appears?

Comment: Nothing shows up, It's like the method never gets used or something.

Comment: So this means that your BT device is not found by your app, this has nothing to do with the textView.

Comment: But it must have found it because it turns bluetooth on with "bluetoothAdapter.enable();"

Comment: I mean that your device that runs your application cannot discover any other Bluetooth enabled devices. It never enters the if statement. Try to debug your code there to see what happens.

Comment: That's strange because when i scan for bluetooth from the settings app on my phone i can see my computer's name listed there.

Comment: Can you put another toast just above the if statement displaying the `action` string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106117/discussion-between-skilo-skilo-and-elefasgr).

Comment: Sorry can't chat at the moment. One more tip. Post you android manifest. Have you enabled the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission?

Comment: Yes i have both BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN in the manifest. The app seems to only work when bluetooth is enabled BEFORE starting the app, If bluetooth is turned on by the app itself nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the problem here.

What's happening is there is a problem when you call bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); right after bluetoothAdapter.enable();

The adapter apparently needs a few seconds to get everything set up before you start doing stuff with it.

So i put a little delay in between those like so:

```
bluetoothAdapter.enable();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);//3 seconds
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

And now everything seems to work.